# Which is correct, "has been pleased to invite you" or "is pleased to invite you"?

Tags: passive-voice

When writing a formal invitation letter for a meeting of which the recipient is a notable person or one with high status, would:

1. His highness has been pleased to invite you for a meeting...
   or
2. His highness is pleased to invite you for a meeting...

be more accurate in terms of tone, formality and grammar? Why?

Extra question: would the answer remain the same if the recipient were to *change* to a person of lower status?

Comment: I'm guessing that the tense isn't important but I'd go for something like:: **His Royal Highness is pleased to invite you (and Mr/s X, partner, etc) to attend ....** whatever.. That's assuming that the person being invited is of lower status than his royal highness. Otherwise, his royal highness might be gratified by the presence of ...etc.

Comment: "Highness" is used only in reference to senior members of reigning royal families.  It should be capitalised, and used with a name.  "His Highness Prince Nikolai..." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highness  Such people don't "invite" they "summon" and not for "meetings" but for "an audience"

Comment: _Be pleased to_ is not passive - it's an adjectival phrase. (_Be pleased **by** something_ is passive).

Answer (score 0):

A few notes:

1. You use the present tense, not a version of the past tense:

> His Royal Highness **is** pleased....

2. You are invited **to** an event (not *for* an event):

> His Royal Highness **is** pleased to invite you **to** a celebration of victory....

These are all extremely formal uses that you might expect to see on some sort of formal printed invitation.

The wording would remain the same regardless of who you were inviting.